# AWS > Load Balancer + Cloudfront - What's the best way

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I've create a Load Balancer.
Now I want to put CloudFront before the Load Balancer.
What's the best way to achieve this?

- I've ACM SSL on amazon for my domain.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this post, describing how to set up an Amazon CloudFront distribution in front of an EC2 origins with an ALB or ELB endpoint: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamic-whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront/